# Altium: What do the different options under Properties (panel) -> General (tab) -> Type, mean?

Tags: altium

Here is the image of the drop down list:

[image]

The "standard" is the default option. But what does Mechanical, Graphical and other options do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I might introduce to you the **F1** key on your keyboard.  Highlight the offending menu-item/button/drop-down, then press the F1 key on your keyboard.  You'll get this:

**Type - Select one of the following component types for the component footprint here. The available types are:**

**Standard** - components that possess standard electrical properties, are always synchronized between the schematic and PCB (the footprint, pins/pads, and net assignments must all match), and are included in the BOM. An example is a standard electrical component, such as a resistor.

**Mechanical** - components that do not have electrical properties, are not synchronized (you must manually place them in both editors), and are included in the BOM. An example is a heatsink.

**Graphical** - components that do not have electrical properties are not synchronized (you must manually place them in both editors), and are not included in the BOM. An example is a company logo.

**Net Tie (In BOM)** - components that are used to short two or more different nets together, are always synchronized between the schematic and PCB (the footprint, pins/pads, and net assignments must all match), and are included in the BOM. They differ from a Standard component in that connectivity created by copper within the footprint is not checked; it is this copper that allows the nets to be shorted. Note: enable the Verify Shorting Copper option in the Design Rule Checker dialog to verify that there is no unconnected copper within the component.

**Net Tie (No BOM)** - components that are used to short two or more different nets together, are always synchronized between the schematic and PCB (the footprint, pins/pads, and net assignments must all match), and are not included in the BOM. They differ from a Standard component in that connectivity created by copper within the footprint is not checked; it is this copper that allows the nets to be shorted. Note: enable the Verify Shorting Copper option in the Design Rule Checker dialog to verify that there is no unconnected copper in the component.

**Standard (No BOM)** - components that possess standard electrical properties, are always synchronized between the schematic and PCB (the footprint, pins/pads, and net assignments must all match), and are not included in the BOM. An example is a testpoint component that you want to exclude from the BOM.

**Jumper** - components that are used to include wire links in a PCB design, for example, on a single-sided PCB that cannot be fully routed on one layer. For this component type, the component footprint and pins are synchronized between the schematic and PCB but the net assignments are not, and the component is included in the BOM. As well as selecting this option at the component level, both of the pads in the component must have their JumperID set to the same non-zero value. Jumper type components do not need to be wired on the schematic; they only need to be included on the schematic if they are required in the BOM. If they are not required in the BOM, they can be placed directly in the PCB where the Component Type is set, the JumperIDs are set, and the Nets manually assigned for the pads.

Also found on:

https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/schematic-part-properties?version=21&help-data=InteractiveProperties.Dlg.Altium_Designer_InteractiveProperties_Views_View_MainView.SchComponent

Comment: The F1 method does not seem to work, it opens web page with error. I shall have to find out why that is.

Comment: Perhaps select: Settings -> System -> View -> General (Section) -> Open internet links in external Web browser